# List filtering compatibile with Material Design?

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with the UI of my app. I have a `RecyclerView` of points and I would like to filter them  with two criteria: 
-distance from current user's position
-elapsed time from point's addition

I have read Material Design guide, but haven't found any guidelines for `List`s' filtering UI patterns. I was thinking of adding drop-down menu to the `Toolbar`, but two dropdown menus would be too much for narrow smartphone portrait-orientation `Toolbar`. What would be the best UI solution for this purpose?

Comment: A dialog would fit, I think.

Comment: I don't believe that's a very good question for StackOverflow. It's a question about design patterns and it's a question to leads to long discussions based on opinion. For those reason I'm making a comment (instead of giving an answer); but I guess you could check Toolbar menu items with sub-menu with checkable items. User clicks on a filter icon, a popup come with options.

Comment: I have the same problem. In my list the user can mark an item as "liked" or "disliked". So I need a way to filter only "liked" items, only "neutral", all items, etc. The way I solved it was using tabs (liked, neutral, disliked) but that doesn't seems to be the best way to handle this problem.

Comment: This question belongs to UX

Answer (score 1):

Material Design offers a solution to this, it is called [Backdrop](https://material.io/design/components/backdrop.html):

> Back layer content can filter front layer content.

Unfortunately, it is currently not supported by the official Material Design Library and [it seems that it won't be anytime soon](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/203#issuecomment-431476668).

There are some two 3rd party libs who can do the job for you:

- https://github.com/kishan2612/Material-Backdrop-Android
- https://github.com/pedromassango/IBackdrop

You can also implement it yourself, check out this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541557/using-backdrop-on-android) answer.