# Using backdrop on Android

Tags: android, material-design

https://material.io/design/components/backdrop.html

I found this on Material Design, but couldn't find any resources.
Thinking about its layout, I think it's made up of any layout with material card view, and I am trying to make my activity file using layout + material card view. Is this method correct to make backdrop layout?

Also, I want to know about which layout I should use. Is RelativeLayout can be the way? I don't get it actually.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This component (BackDrop) is still under development for the [Android Material Components](https://material.io/develop/android/) library as of **16 December 2018**.

However, if you are using Material Components already, it's not that hard to implement your own. You will need the following:

- [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout) as the root layout
- a [BottomSheetBehaviour](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/) applied to an immediate child of the root layout

The provided solution below, looks like the following image...

[image]

The example below uses a fragment, I'll ommit the details of the hosting activity because it is irrelevant to the question/answer. However, you can do exactly the same with an activity. Your fragment layout file will look like below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--This the interface sitting behind the backdrop and shown when it is collapsed-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_spacing">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search_primary_xlight_24dp"
            style="@style/EditTextStyle.Inverse.Large.Light"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/datesFilterButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_calendar_primary_xlight_24dp"
            style="@style/EditTextStyle.Inverse.Large.Light"
            android:hint="@string/select_dates_hint"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--This is the backdrop's content with a BottomSheetBehaviour applied to it-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <!--This is the backdrop's header with a title and icon-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_list_header_background"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_spacing"
            android:elevation="4dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.Stems.Body2"
                android:text="0 items(s)"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/filterIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_filter_black_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--And finally this is the body of the backdrop's content. You can add here whatever you need inside a view group (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, SwipeRefreshLayout, ConstraintLayout, etc.)-->
        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorBackground">

             <!--The content's body goes here-->
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </LinearLayout>   


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

There's a couple of things you need to be aware of here. First, the `LinearLayout` that sits behind the backdrop its using the `colorPrimary` color which exactly the same as the `Toolbar`'s background color...the toolbar has been ommitted for clarity, it is declared in the hosting activity (remember, this solution is for a fragment).

Then the fragment's class will look like this...

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hazards, container, false);

        Context context = getContext();

        if(context != null){
            setTitle(context.getString(R.string.title_hazards));
        }

        filterIcon = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.filterIcon);
        LinearLayout contentLayout = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.contentLayout);

        sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(contentLayout);
        sheetBehavior.setFitToContents(false);
        sheetBehavior.setHideable(false);//prevents the boottom sheet from completely hiding off the screen
        sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);//initially state to fully expanded

        filterIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                toggleFilters();
            }
        });


        return coordinatorLayout;
    }

    private void toggleFilters(){
        if(sheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED){
            sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED);
        }
        else {
            sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    }
```

And that's it, the only thing you need to keep in mind is that root layout has to be a `CoordinatorLayout` and that the `BottomSheetBehaviour` has to be applied to an immediate child of the root layout

#### Round Corners

You will also notice that I'm not using a `CardView` in the BackDrop's header to get the nice rounded corners the `CardView` comes with. That's because I only need the top corners to be rounded and the default implementation of `CardView` doesn't allow you to explicitly set individual corners. Instead, I used a good old `LinearLayout` and provided my own drawable for its background (`ic_list_header_background`). Here's the xml declaration of this drawable...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorBackground" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp" android:topRightRadius="16dp" />

</shape>
```

Nothing really fancy, just a rectangular shape with selective rounded corners (the top ones)

#### Toolbar's Drop Shadow

You will want to remove the ToolBar's drop shadow, to do so, you can set its elevation to `0dp` or programmatically remove the outline provider on the parent `AppBarLayout` as below...

```
appBarLayout.setOutlineProvider(null);
```

obviously, this is assuming that your `Toolbar` is inside an `AppBarLayout` as per the guidelines

I hope this really helps someone out there while the Material Component's BackDrop is still under development. It's not perfect because you are still bound to the functionalities exposed by the BottomSheetBehaviour component that it's quite limited. But if you are picky or want to go fancy, I'd recommend implementing your own BottomSheetBehaviour by extending the default one

#### Disabling user's swipe gesture

Based on [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/design/components/backdrop.html#behavior), it is recommended not to use swipe gestures on the front layer of the backdrop

> Don’t use the swipe gesture on the front layer to reveal the back layer.

However, by default, the `BottomSheetBehaviour` doesn't expose any properties or APIs to disable swipe gestures. To achieve that, you will need to implement your own by extending the `BottomSheetBehaviour` overriding all gesture-related methods. Here's an example I'm using in one of my projects (written in Kotlin)

```
class GestureLockedBottomSheetBehavior<V: View>(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?) : BottomSheetBehavior<V>(context, attributeSet){

    constructor(context: Context):this(context, null)

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, event: MotionEvent): Boolean = false

    override fun onTouchEvent(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, event: MotionEvent): Boolean = false

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
        child: V,
        directTargetChild: View,
        target: View,
        axes: Int,
        type: Int
    ): Boolean = false

    override fun onNestedPreScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
        child: V,
        target: View,
        dx: Int,
        dy: Int,
        consumed: IntArray,
        type: Int
    ) { }

    override fun onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, target: View, type: Int) { }

    override fun onNestedFling(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
        child: V,
        target: View,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float,
        consumed: Boolean
    ): Boolean = false
}
```

Even if you're not familiar with Kotlin it shouldn't be hard to figure out that all I'm doing is overriding a bunch on methods and return false or doing nothing by not calling the super class's counterpart

Then to use this `GestureLockedBottomSheetBehavior` class, you will need to replace it in your layout as below...

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
        app:layout_behavior="ui.behaviors.GestureLockedBottomSheetBehavior">
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Just make sure the fully-qualified name is set according to the package your custom class resides in.

Comment: This works really well, but there's something, when the user tries to scroll up the bottomsheet goes down instead, are there any solutions ?

Comment: @TamimAttafi Well, the code in this answer is not production-ready. In fact, based on Material Design Guidelines, you shouldn't be allowing swipe gestures on the front layer of the BackDrop. I've just updated the answer to explain how to disable swipe gestures

Comment: @Leo: How did you make the gif animation? Thanks!

Comment: @stefan I can't remember. Just take the mp4 generated by Android Studio and Google "mp4 to gif". You'll get a lot of hits on that search term

Comment: Does anyone have the EditText style? (EditTextStyle.Inverse.Large.Light)

Comment: perfect explanation

Answer (score 6):

It is under development right now ([**Backdrop github page**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Backdrop.md)).

Code & how to.. would be available once it's developed. So, right now you have to create your own customized backdrop or wait for it.

I'll suggest if you want to do it, then take **FrameLayout** and add some **CardView**
in it with some margins to get look like backdrop, add some animations on transitions to it & your custom backdrop would be ready.

Comment: I added a cardview, but I'm not sure how to make it full-screen. I want to get the cardview fill the screen when scrolled. Is this available via ScrollView?

Comment: You should change `layoutparams` programmatically for expanding your cardview. Share some code, i'll look into it and provide some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a small modification to Leo's answer:

I'm using a `RecyclerView` inside a `LinearLayout`. This `LinearLayout` is my bottomsheet. Using the `GestureLockedBottomSheetBehavior` as suggested by Leo does not allow the `RecyclerView` to scroll and the following is what I did to overcome that problem.

This is the custom bottomsheet behavior class that I used finally to make the `RecyclerView` scroll.

```
class GestureLockedBottomSheetBehavior<V: View>(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : BottomSheetBehavior<V>(context, attributeSet){

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, event: MotionEvent): Boolean = false

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
        child: V,
        directTargetChild: View,
        target: View,
        axes: Int,
        type: Int
    ): Boolean = false
}
```

With this my `RecyclerView` is scrolling. But it scrolls only when the state of the bottom sheet is `STATE_EXPANDED` and the `RecyclerView` does not scroll when the state of the bottom sheet is `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED`.

If anyone knows how to solve this, it would be very helpful.

Comment: I've done this several times and I think all you have to do is enable nested scrolling on the recycleview. In kotlin...`recyclerview.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true`

Answer (score 0):

Our implementation using Linear Layout and Bottom Sheet Behavior here:
https://github.com/keikenofficial/keiken-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/keiken/view/backdrop

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11440565/64996052-26b0be00-d8dd-11e9-95f8-f643ec68e679.gif

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11440565/64996027-1567b180-d8dd-11e9-9f50-549479ff0480.gif

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11440565/64996019-100a6700-d8dd-11e9-8592-1c9d55b439ce.gif

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11440565/64996044-1d275600-d8dd-11e9-8fd1-8780859c74e1.gif)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30909453)